# Why PageSpeed Insights keep telling "web browser is out of date" during his own check?

Tags: symfony, google-chrome, browser, pagespeed, google-pagespeed

I try to check my website in Google PageSpeed Insights.

Any page. For example this - https://simplex.ua/ua/prep-germany

Here is screenshot of his check with message "Your web browser (Chrome 109) is out of date. Update your browser for more security, speed and the best experience on this site.":

[the error at the top](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wwDlS.jpg)

And of course PageSpeed tells me that Cumulative Layout Shift is - 0.138

How it can be possible?
How to eliminate this, so CLS can be 0 again?

My website is running on Symfony. Does it mean something wrong with it?

I honestly don't know what to do. Ind google gives me nothing :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A few things are going on here:

- PSI is using a browser identifying itself as Chrome 109. That is indeed out of date but also out of your hands. As you said in a [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77496166/why-pagespeed-insights-keep-telling-web-browser-is-out-of-date-during-his-own#comment136621693_77496208), it's not using your browser so there's nothing you can do to update it. It's also possible the browser being used isn't out of date at all and it's just the user agent string is old.
- The warning you're seeing is from the inclusion of a [browser-update.org](https://browser-update.org/) script in the page to give that top warning to out of date browsers. I'm not sure how exactly it's included because it's bundled into your js, but you can see the snippet at the top of your `main.js` (the `$buo_f` function...see the matching reference from the [browser-update docs here](https://browser-update.org/#install)). If you don't need for users to have the latest browser versions (most sites don't), I'd suggest removing that function from wherever it's added to your bundle.
- If for some reason you have to have that browser version check warning, PSI correctly points out that the top cause of CLS on the page is from `margin-top` on the page's body, which the brower-update script added to shift the page's content below the warning bar. According to [the browser-update customization docs](https://browser-update.org/customize.html), there are a few options that may help here. Setting `shift_page_down` to false would prevent `margin-top` being used, though it would then block some page content. You could also try `style: 'bottom'` to see if however it adds it to the bottom of the page still causes CLS (it might not).

Answer (score 0):

You need to update your browser first.  Go to "About Chrome" and update.
Then try to check PageSpeed one more time.

Comment: I don't think so. My chrome is up to date. And as I understand - PageSpeed does not uses my chrome during check. So why this error appearing then?